Convert UTC timezone to local time zone
I have a report where all the dates should be displayed in the client's time zone. The report includes a feature that allows exporting to Excel. For both generating the report and exporting it to Excel, I am using the same procedure. All the dates are stored in UTC in the database. I tried to convert the UTC date to the client's local time zone using the following code in SQL Server:
DateUtc AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE @TimeZoneName AS dateTimeCreated

@TimeZoneName is passed via procedure parameter. I tried to get the name of client's time zone name in javascript by following code.
const date = new Date();

const timeZoneString = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
    timeZoneName: 'long'
}).format(date);

const timeZoneName = timeZoneString.split(',')[1].trim();

console.log(timeZoneName)

This code doesn't return consistent values. For example, if I am in the (UTC-12:00) International Date Line West time zone, JavaScript returns the value as GMT-12:00. However, if I am in Nepal Time, it returns a random value for each time zone. If I pass the exact value provided by JavaScript to the procedure, the procedure throws an exception as shown below:
The time zone parameter 'Nepal Time' provided to AT TIME ZONE clause is invalid.

How to resolve this issue? Anyone knows the answer please help me
I tried to use the TimeZoneOffset value, but it causes issues during daylight saving time

You can run: select * from sys.time_zone_info and see the names of zones you need to pass

If you can't pass the correct timezone, why not fetch data from sql server in utc and then do the conversion in the javascript scripts of things before generating the excel-file.

@siggemannen I can conver to local time in javascript but how can i do in excel's data. Excel is exported from backend.

How, sql server can't create files? And what's your backend running

JavaScript Intl API can get you the IANA time zone name:
let timezoneName_iana = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
// Asia/Kathmandu

If you're using .NET 6+ as the bridge between the browser and SQL Server you may use the TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertIanaIdToWindowsId method:
string timezoneName_iana = "Asia/Kathmandu";
TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertIanaIdToWindowsId(timezoneName_iana, out string? timezoneName_win);
// Nepal Standard Time

This name should work with AT TIME ZONE function in SQL Server.

I have export it to excel as well. So i wanted to do this in sql procedure.
Converting to local timezone using javascript works well but i can't to while export excel.

Your JavaScript code needs to return the same values as those in sys.time_zone_info which would be "Windows standard format". I doublt if JavaScript and SQL Server agree on some common standard.

any solution to get the exact value from JavaScript

Your sample code should return "Nepal Standard Time" instead of "Nepal Time". If it doesn't, try little brute force e.g. by matching only the country name or remove "Standard" from both strings (one coming from JavaScript and other coming from sys.timezoneinfo) then compare.

Is .Net code (somewhere in the middle) an option?

.net code will be on server so it only return the timezone of server only

I need to export it to excel - what are you using to export to excel?

@Chris I have revised my answer.

@fdomn-m Export is on service side. Javascript call the .net api and .net api calls the java api for export

..so... reformat in the .net or "java"?  Standard paradigm is that SQL should only provide the raw data and other tiers determine the presentation.
